# Is the product of closed subgroups in topological group closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Just out of curiosity: If $G$ is a topological group and $H, K$ are closed subgroups, is $H\cdot K$ a closed subgroup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, take $G$ is the group of real numbers $\Bbb R$, $H$ is $\Bbb Z$ and $K$ is $\Bbb Zx$ where $x$ is irrational. The group $H.K$ is dense.

Comment: … and proper, just to say it.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not true. In the additive group of real numbers, the subgroups generated by $1$ and $\pi$ are closed, but their product is dense and not all of $\mathbb R$, so it is not closed.