# Set product of two closed subspaces of a topological group

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Given $A$ and $B$ are closed sets in a topological group $G$, how can I show $AB=\{ab | a\in$ A and $b \in B\}$ is closed in $G$? All we have learned so far is the definition of a topological group. (And the point-set topology until the beginning of quotient topology).

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ arbitrary closed sets?

Comment: The answer is negative, even if $A$ and $B$ are subgroups. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1781180/is-the-product-of-closed-subgroups-in-topological-group-closed).

Comment: @J.-E. Pin Thank you! And Thomas Shelby, yes,  A and B are arbitrary closed sets.